How to make sense to the commutative relation between tensor and $^*$?
Let $V$ be $R$-module. I can prove that $(V \otimes_{R} V)^* \cong V^* \otimes_{R} V^*$. My proof is a bit cumbersome, and it is by analyzing the elements. So  my proof is not natural, it depends on the selection of one basis. I would like to know if there is a more structured understanding. For example, I have a sense of adjointness of Hom and Tensor, and I think it's a good sense. So then I want to know if I can find a natural way to $(V \otimes_{R} V)^* \cong V^* \otimes_{R} V^*$.

This doesn't hold for (general) modules. Please enter "tensor product dual" or something into the search box. You will find several duplicates. Also it is a bad idea to work out isomorphisms between tensor products by using elements. You want to use the universal property and already derived properties as much as you can.
